# Why the correlation between factors are penalized when weight is large negative in Oblimin rotation?

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis, factor-rotation, rotation

I'm facing difficulties in interpreting the criterion for the Oblimin rotation.

In my knowledge, the following criterion shall be minimized in oblimin rotation.

$$\sum_{ij} (\sum_{v}{l_i}^2{l_j}^2 - \frac{w}{k}\sum_{v}{l_i}^2\sum_{v}{l_j}^2) $$

Where $\sum_{ij}$ means the sum over all factor pairs ij (i>j)},
and $\sum_{v}$ means sum across variables (w for weight, and k for number of variables, l for loadings).

For instance, I believe that the criterion will look like as follow when you have 3 variables and 2 factors, depending on the value of w (sorry for my bad handwriting I had a difficulty in expressing l11 in html).

[image]

My textbook says that when w is large negative (-15 for instance), the high correlations between factors are penalized.

But I don't really see why how correlation between factors is penalized, in the criterion expression, when w=-15 compared to w=0.

To be more specific, what part of the criterion expression stand for the correlation between factors? And why?

And how the value of w affect the former in the expression?

I would really appreciate any help.